# Value of property binded to a TextBlock inside a User Control is not being detected

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, user-controls, windows-phone

I've created a UserControl, LiveTile.xaml (streamlined for brevity):

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Weathercast.Core.LiveTile"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Weathercast.Core">

    <StackPanel 
        x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <StackPanel 
            x:Name="TileRegularFront" 
            Width="336"
            Height="336"
            Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TempCurrentHour}"/>
     </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Its code behind, LiveTile.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class LiveTile : UserControl
{
    public LiveTile()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LiveTileViewModel vm = new LiveTileViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

Its view model, LiveTileViewModel.cs:

```
public class LiveTileViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    /** PROPERTIES **/

    private string _tempCurrentHour;
    public string TempCurrentHour
    {
        get { return _tempCurrentHour; }
        set
        {
            _tempCurrentHour = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TempCurrentHour");
        }
    }


    /** CONSTRUCTOR **/

    public LiveTileViewModel()
    {
        this.TempCurrentHour = "15"; // dummy value set
    }

}
```

ObservableObject.cs:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the value I'm binding ("TempCurrentHour") is not being displayed. Any ideas on what I need to do in order to get the User Control's View Model's binded property value to display? Based on my research, I believe binding a value to a User Control is less straightforward than normal. However I can't get my head around what needs to be done to get the User Control to detect binded property values.

UPDATE: Just to be clear, the LiveTile class is in a Library project for my solution. An instance of it is created when the user toggles on the Live Tile via the Settings PhoneApplicationPage located in the Windows Phone App project in the solution. This is the event handler that instantiates a LiveTile in Settings.xaml.cs:

```
    private void LiveTile_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            Weathercast.Core.LiveTile l = new Weathercast.Core.LiveTile();
            l.CreateOrUpdateTile(1);
    }
```

The CreateOrUpdateTile method is doing its job correctly and takes the user back to their phone's Start screen with the Live Tile now there. This is its code in any case (I'm using Telerik's LiveTileHelper):

```
            RadFlipTileData tileData = new RadFlipTileData()
            {
                VisualElement = this.TileRegularFront,
                BackVisualElement = this.TileRegularBack,
                SmallVisualElement = this.TileSmall
            };

            // Tile's uri has a unique paramater which is the location Id of the currently viewed location.
            Uri tileUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?locationId=" + locationId, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            // If the tile for this location previously existed, delete it before adding it anew.
            ShellTile tile = LiveTileHelper.GetTile(tileUri);
            if (tile != null)
            {
                tile.Delete();
            }

            // Create brand new tile for location if didn't have tile previously or fresh tile if it did.
            LiveTileHelper.CreateOrUpdateTile(tileData, tileUri, true);

            this.tile = tileData;

            // Add the Background Agent for this tile with the agent's name
            // unique for the location.
            AddAgent("PeriodicTaskForLocation" + locationId);
```

I should note another problem I'm having, that may or may not be related to the original issue, is that the background property I'm setting in LiveTile.xaml for the StackPanel or LayoutRoot element even is being neglected and the Live Tile that's being added to the Start screen is transparent (black).

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code as far as I can see (except StackPanel doesn't have Text property : `<StackPanel ... Text="{Binding TempCurrentHour}"/>`, typo?)

Comment: yeah same thing i noticed there cant be nay text property in a stackpanel and one more this have you added this usercontrol in any of your view ?

Comment: My bad when 'streamlining' code for my post I made a mistake and used a StackPanel incorrectly. In the actual code the binding value is for a TextBlock. So that's not the problem I'm afraid.

Comment: Fixed the coding typo in original post and updated summary too to reflect this correction.

Comment: Sandeep, no I haven't used it any of my views. What I'm doing is creating a new instance of LiveTile() from Settings.xaml.cs when the user selects for there to be a live tile. I'll add this code to original post in case it's relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: Added more code to original post to give a fuller picture of what's going on.